# Rails - Best way to have an api call whenever object is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model, devise, controller

What is the best way to have an api called whenever an object is updated?

Placing the call inside the model with `after_update` doesn't seem very clean, and in some cases it may be necessary to have the `current_user` from `devise`. Also calling the api everywhere that the object is changed (we have a few ways to save a sale, for instance) doesn't sound very clear either

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Ok, so first of all, I think you should define what you want, in the pos title you wrote `...whenever object is updated`, but in the post body you wrote `...calling the api everywhere that the object is changed doesn't sound very clear`. So, first of all define what you really want. If you want this call to be executed just in some cases, why don't you define a helper class that updates the record ?, use that class, and after updating it, just fire the api call in that class ?. And use that class wherever you want this to happen.

Comment: what I want is in the title.. to know what is the best way to call an api sending the object every time it is updated, no matter where in the project. Using a class to save it won't work, because depending from where the object is saved, some things change, like I said in the question.

Comment: the `after_update` callback is intended for exactly this purpose. Not sure why it "doesn't seem very clean" to you.

Comment: I think there are different ways to accomplish what you want. What would the best solution be ?, it depends. You might be entering to a pattern zone, it is up to you which one fits best. But what I can tell you is that a class can help you here. A class which receives in initialize the object to save, and extra optional params that can be used. Then, you can define a `save` method, there you can call save on the object passed, if it is successful call the api, you already have extra params to use, there you could send the user or whatever you want. Find a pattern that suits your needs.

Comment: you could even use publish & subscribe approach as well, you could use `ActiveSupport::Notifications` for that if you want.

Comment: the `after_update`callback would work, but are models the right place to make api calls?

Comment: How about creating a new service class(preferably in app/services folder) and making an api call there. You can call that service class method inside the controller update api if the update was successful. No need to add it in model. If you want to make an api call everytime an object is updated even internally ( as in some other object updated the concerned objet) then after_update makes sense.

Comment: that would work, the problem is that I have the object being created/updated in multiple places.. What I was looking for was something like that, but that triggered when the object was created/updated, something like `after_update`, but ouside of the model

Comment: you mean, outside of the model just to not clutter it with many things ?, or out of the model because you think it does not belong there ?. If it's just because you don't want to clutter your model, you could use an observer, and do it there.

Comment: because I think api calls don't belong there

Comment: I personally do not like that as well. I think models should be used to save, and perhaps base validations, that's it. With that said, I guess you can do what Akshay said, a class in services folder, call save on your object, if it passes then make the api call, you'd need to use that class whenever you want to make the api call. A pub sub approach could also work, not sure what you prefer.